# Reducing Amazon RDS costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an Amazon RDS instance class `db.m1.medium`. I would like to downgrade to `db.m1.small` to save on costs since it's not being used much.

When I do this, are there any software changes involved? My concern is that settings will get changed when it downgrades. I don't want anything getting corrupt or MySQL settings getting changed.

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Modifying.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RDS settings will not be automatically changed if you change the instance type. However, you should check the monitoring on the `db.m1.medium` before downgrading to make sure you'd have enough memory in a `db.m1.small`. You'd be dropping from 3.75GB to 1.7GB.

Comment: Also your RDS instance will be unavailable for several minutes while it's being resized. If an application needs data on that instance, you should put up a maintenance page for that app until the resize operation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some information and some concepts explaining what are the most expensive parts of RDS and how to plan to reduce costs. See if it helps https://shatteredsilicon.net/blog/2021/06/10/how-to-reduce-rds-costs-on-aws/